# AWS Java Lambda Handler to Start/Stop RDS instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to create a Java Lambda Handler to start and stop rds instances for AWS. Very confused on how to do this since most of the online resources are in python. I took a look at the AWS Java SDK to see what functions I need to use (startDBInstance, stopDBInstance), but am unsure how to implement them properly as this is my first time doing so.

This is the outline of the Handler.

```
package com.example.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are doing this from a Lambda function? Are you trying to stop the RDS instance overnight, for example, to reduce costs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track in terms of using the Java Lambda runtime. To modify RDS resources from a Lambda function, use the **RDS Java API** within the Lambda function.

[software.amazon.awssdk.services.rds.RdsClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/rds/RdsClient.html)

To stop the instance, for example, you call **stopDBInstance()**.

There is a Java Lambda example here that shows you how to use the AWS Java APIs (this example uses serveral service clients) from within a Lambda function.This shows how to create an IAM user that the Lambda function uses, how to specify AWS dependencies in the POM, etc.

For you use case, you need to use the RDS Java Client. You still need to create an IAM user (that your Lambda function uses) and specify the RDS POM dependency in your project's POM. (All shown in the example below).

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels

**TIP**: WHen looking for examples that uses the **AWS SDK for Java**, refer to here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2

You will find only Java examples, not Python, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there any more specific help you could give me in terms of how long this code segment will likely be or how exactly to implement the stop and start into this Lambda as this is my first time working with this and I am a little lost.

Comment: You can find RDS API examples here that will help you. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/rds

Comment: Take a look at the Java example in Source. All you need to do is to hook this RDS API into a Lambda function project - as shown in the above article i referenced in my answer.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable working with an AWS SDK then I'd recommend that you learn how to use the awscli first [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/stop-db-instance.html). Use it to stop/start RDS instances. It will then be simpler for you to understand what you need to do when programing with the Java SDK.

Comment: Still a little confused on the direct implementation on it having seen the resources you've provided. I have already pushed a CloudFormation script through a pipeline to create the IAM roles and policies but am not sure how to start/stop in the Lambda Handler function itself. Is there any way I could connect with someone who could help me with this more personally?